# Find repeated characters in a word using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that finds repeated characters in a word using python 3.x.

For instance,

```
"abcde" -> 0 # no characters repeats more than once
"aabbcde" -> 2 # 'a' and 'b'
"aabBcde" -> 2 # 'a' occurs twice and 'b' twice (bandB)
"indivisibility" -> 1 # 'i' occurs six times
```

Here is the code I have so far,

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    my_list=list(text)
    final=[]
    for i in my_list:
        if i in final:
            return(len(final[i]))


        else:
            return(0)
```

I want to grow in my python skills so I want to understand what's going wrong with it and why.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't know what is going wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your code is supposed to do: you never put anything in `final` and you `return` immediately.

The below solution keeps two `set`s as it iterates over the input.  One is every character we've seen, the other is every character that occurs more than once.  We use `set`s because they have very fast membership checking, and because when you try to add an item to a `set` that already contains that item, nothing happens:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    seen = set()
    more_than_one = set()
    for letter in text:
        if letter in seen:
            more_than_one.add(letter)
        else:
            seen.add(letter)
    return len(more_than_one)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to grow in my python skills so I want to understand what's going wrong with it and why.
>
> Any ideas?

Well, for one thing, since you never actually put anything in "final" you will never have a case for which "i" is in "final"...

Here's a function that will do what you want:

```
def do_stuff(test_str):
    my_list=list(test_str)
    my_dict={}
    count=0
    for i in my_list:
        if i in my_dict:
            my_dict[i]+=1
        else:
            my_dict[i]=1
    for k in my_dict:
        if my_dict[k]>1:
            count+=1
    return count
```

This function can be improved (by you).